# How to determinte how much space to allocate for boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-stacktrace

I'm looking at the `boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to` API and I cannot for the life of me work out how to determine how much space to allocate for the `safe_dump_to()` call. If I pass `(nullptr, 0)`, it just returns `0`, so that's not it. I could guess some constant number, but how do i know that's enough?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/stacktrace/reference.html#header.boost.stacktrace.safe_dump_to_hpp) specify:

> This header contains low-level async-signal-safe functions for dumping call stacks. Dumps are binary serialized arrays of void*, so you could read them by using 'od -tx8 -An stacktrace_dump_failename' Linux command or using boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump functions.

[And additionally](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/stacktrace/safe_dump_1_3_37_7_6_2_1_1.html)

> Returns:
>
> Stored call sequence depth including terminating zero frame. To get the actually consumed bytes multiply this value by the sizeof(boost::stacktrace::frame::native_frame_ptr_t))

It's not overly explicit, but this means you need `sizeof(boost::stacktrace::frame::native_frame_ptr_t)*N` where N is the number of stackframes in the trace.

Now of course, you can find out `N`, but there is not [async-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html#:%7E:text=An%20async%2Dsignal%2Dsafe%20function,from%20within%20a%20signal%20handler.&text=If%2C%20at%20that%20moment%2C%20the,inconsistent%20data%2C%20with%20unpredictable%20results.) way to do allocate dynamically anyways, so you'd simply have to pick a number that suits your application. E.g. 256 frames might be reasonable, but you should look at your own needs (e.g. DEBUG builds will show a *lot more* stack frames, especially with code that heavily relies on template generics, YMMV).

Since the whole `safe_dump_to` construct is designed to be async-safe, I always just use the [overload that writes to a file](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/stacktrace/safe_dump_1_3_37_7_6_2_1_3.html). When reading it back (typically after a restart) you will be able to deduce the number of frames from the file-size.

> Optionally see [some of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+safe_dump_to) for code samples/more background information

Comment: you say " you can find out N", but my whole question is "how do you find out N" & "I could guess some constant number, but how do i know that's enough?"

Comment: Note that I also explained why that is how it is, and how you can avoid it. Of course I can tell you how to find N (after looking at the documentation again) but **it will be of no use** because if you do the allocation you have Undefined Behavior

Comment: I don’t seem to remember my question asking how to do dynamic allocation at _any_ time. My only question is how to determine N.

Comment: Fair point. I'd look at the implementation of `safe_dump_to` on _async-safe_ ways to get the count: [sadly](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7X2XrNSPQW/) that leads to undocumented implementation details. The normal public interface through `basic_stacktrace` appears to be not-async-safe. Maybe you explain what you are trying to achieve? Since you only mentioned the context of `safe_dump_to` I had to assume async-safe code is important.